# Magenoto2: how to get cart item quantity on front end

Tags: magento2, cart, quantity

I am currently using this code and it is working fine,

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$totalQuantity = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsQty();
```

but it is not working on few category pages as well as Home page in my theme.
Please help.

Comment: you can get cart data from session

Comment: Do you want to get total qty of all items? Or of the particular item?

Comment: qty of all items @stepan

Comment: Did you try what Nikhil advice?

Comment: @Nikhil actually the code i am using is present in design section of theme so i don't know how to use session there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get what i need using these code but thanku all

```
<block class="<Vendor>\Cart\Block\Cart" before="-" template="<Vendor>_Cart::cart-panel.phtml" name="cart-panel" cacheable="false" />
```

in my theme default.xml

Answer (score 3):

use below code

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $currentCustomer
) { 
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;   
 }
 
 
 $cartQuote=$this->checkoutSession->getQuote();  
 $items=$cartQuote->getAllItems();
```

Or

```
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $checkoutSession = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
  $cartQuote=$checkoutSession->getQuote();  
  $items=$cartQuote->getAllItems();
```

Comment: is there any way to use above method using object manager

Comment: Yes you can get via objectManager (Please check update ans.)

Comment: It should be '\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session' instead of '\Magento\Customer\Model\Session'